# Does `∃! x, ∃! y, P (x, y)` imply `∃! xy, P (fst xy) (snd xy)`?

Tags: coq

It is comparatively easy to prove the following (Coq):

```
Goal forall A (P : A -> A -> Prop), (exists! xy, P (fst xy) (snd xy)) -> (exists! x, exists! y, P x y).
```

The question I am puzzled with: does the reverse hold? The `exists x, exists y, ...` formulation allows `y` to be chosen based on what `x` got selected one step back, so `y` is admitted to be **dependent upon `x`**. It seems to me (at least, I am not able to convince myself otherwise) that `exists xy, ...` - a pair `(x, y)` existence is different: it does not allow `y` to be chosen based on `x`.

The fun fact is that I tried to prove both `Goal forall A (P : A -> A -> Prop), (exists! x, exists! y, P x y) -> ~ (exists! xy, P (fst xy) (snd xy)).` and it's negation and both times got stuck with not being able to construct a required object or derive `False`.

Please, help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse does not hold. Here is a counterexample:

```
Definition P (x y : bool) : Prop :=
  x = true -> y = true.

Lemma l1 : exists! x, exists! y, P x y.
Proof.
exists true.
split.
- exists true. split; [easy|].
  now intros y ->.
- intros x' (y & Py & unique_y).
  destruct x'; trivial.
  assert (contra : P false (negb y)).
  { intros; easy. }
  specialize (unique_y (negb y) contra).
  now destruct y.
Qed.

Lemma l2 : ~ (exists! xy, P (fst xy) (snd xy)).
Proof.
intros ([x y] & Pxy & unique_xy); simpl in *.
assert (contra : P (negb x) true).
{ intros ?. reflexivity. }
specialize (unique_xy (negb x, true) contra).
injection unique_xy as contra' _.
now destruct x.
Qed.
```

Comment: All right, but you prove it for quite a certain `P` using comparability of `bool` extensively AFAICS. Is there a way to prove the same `forall P`?

Comment: @Zazaeil You cannot refute the result for all predicates P. For instance, `P x y` could be `x = true /\ y = true`, in which case the converse would hold.

Comment: Thanks. P.S. Quite elegant tactics manipulation. I learned few new things.